# Wrapping between nowraps

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a list of links that should be displayed inline.
The thing is I do not want the text to wrap in the middle of links. If it needs to wrap, it should only do so ***between*** links.

I have therefore added the `white-space:nowrap;` property to my link. But the resulting list of links ***never*** wraps and gets out of my `div` box.

Any idea how I can get my list to wrap between the links? Thank you!

```
<div class="box">
<p>
<a href="mylink1" class="mytag">Hello there</a>
<a href="mylink2" class="mytag">Hello you</a>
<a href="mylink3" class="mytag">Hello people</a>
<a href="mylink4" class="mytag">Hello world</a>
</p>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS is just:

```
.mytag,.mytag:link,.mytag:visited{
  background-color:#FFF5CA;
  border:1px solid #FFE5B5;
  color:#222;
  padding:2px 5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.mytag:hover{
  background-color:#FFE5B5;
}
```

Comment: you are right, I didn't know that percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `white-space:nowrap;` is doing exactly what it is supposed and that is not breaking the elements into multiple lines.

What you are actually looking for is to display the links on a single line, without the links wrapping onto the next line. Therefore, use  a `display` property as `inline-block`.

```
.mytag,.mytag:link,.mytag:visited{
  background-color:#FFF5CA;
  border:1px solid #FFE5B5;
  color:#222;
  padding:2px 5px;
  margin-right:5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @Madbreaks, Try it with `inline-block` it does not wrap on multiple line. :)

Comment: It works fine with `inline-block`, thank you! I hope this property is compatible with all frequently used browsers :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything mysterious here - they should automatically wrap between links if your container has a specific widhth:  http://jsfiddle.net/RZfd2/

Comment: I don't want to have wraps between all links. Only to prevent my list getting too wide. So it is _authorized_ to wrap between links, but not _forced_ to

Comment: @Eric, what you describe is exactly what happens in the jsfiddle. You need to be more specific about the problem you have observed: on which browser(s), in which context—please provide a full page that demonstrates the problem. The code that you provides does not do that, except in the sense that on Firefox, wrapping does not take place, since it has some bugs in wrapping in narrow windows.